# Best way to create a forever cookie when a user accesses the website in Laravel

Tags: laravel, cookies

I'm looking for the best way to create a cookie that doesn't expire when a user visits the website (the cookie holds uuid). I am using Laravel, and from what I can tell the best way seems to be using Middleware. PLease can anyone advise otherwise, and also any code examples.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show some code examples.

Comment: Are you trying to store it in the client's browser forever?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use middleware for this, create a `SetUserCookie` middleware or similar:

```
class SetUserCookie { 
    public function handle($request, Closure $next) {
        $response = $next($request);
        return $response->withCookie(cookie()->forever('uuid', Str::uuid()));
    }
 }
```

Register the middleware in the kernel:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    ...
    'setUserCookie' => \App\Http\Middleware\SetUserCookie::class, 
    ...
];
```

You can also use the queue method to attach a cookie to a response:

```
$minutes = 60 * 24 * 365 * 10; // ten years should be long enough
Cookie::queue(Cookie::make('uuid', Str::uuid(), $minutes));

Cookie::queue('uuid', Str::uuid(), $minutes);
```

[Request docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/requests#cookies)

Comment: Worked great, needed to register the middleware  in protected $middleware and just added some checks to see if the cookie exists first. Thanks